# Call a function when PYD (python + c++) module is being unloaded

Tags: c++, python, onunload, pyd

I need to run some extra functions when I load a PYD and when I unload it because c++ core uses a module written in another language and this module needs to be loaded and unloaded manually.

I call load_another_language_module() in initMY_PYD_NAME(void) and it works fine.

Would there be a similar function for me to implement that will be called when my PYD is being unloaded? I can wrap unload_another_language_module() so that it is runnable in Python and call in every script manually, but it is not terrbily convenient.

Thanks in advance!